# How to store row and column of excel into array (more than 1 column and 1 row)

Tags: excel, vba

May I know to to store A1:AD10 into one single array vba? should i use 2 dimensional array? Thanks

Comment: If you want to ask another question, use the ask question button. Don't edit your existing questions.

Comment: @DanD. Hi, yes i know but i got this error when i want to ask. "You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
MyArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AD10").Value
```

This will read the whole range into an 2 dimensional array that you can access with

```
Debug.Print MyArray(row, column)
```

where `row` and `column` must be within the dimensions of the array `1 … n`.